# variable voltage divider using transistors

Tags: voltage, transistors, sensor, analog, water

I found this schematic for a water level indicator:
[sensor schematic](http://bp3.blogger.com/_IrQ3pWfzbLQ/R4-mFFQO4eI/AAAAAAAAAHI/H0NESRgTo0w/s1600-h/depth+sensor.jpg)

I would like to modify it some.  Namely, instead of illuminating LEDs I would like to make it a variable resistor (aka make a voltage divider circuit out of it).  I would be using it in the same application though (i.e. stainless screws in a PVC pipe to sense water level by contact method).

Here is the application this schematic came from: [sensor application](http://pscmpf.blogspot.com/2007/12/sump-pump-monitor.html)

In my application I want to supply Vcc with 5VDC and have the circuit divide that to an analog input on an Arduino.

I redlined the schematic to what I think might work, but I'm not an analog circuits expert.  I would appreciate any guidance or links or ??? whatever can help me out.  Here is my redline (PS the R value of the resistor(s) i've added is TBD):
[image]

Comment: *I'm not an analog circuits expert* Yeah, that's clear. This is not going to work. Once any of the transistors starts to conduct the output will be pulled high. You would have no indication of water level at all just water (at any contact) or no water at all.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie: You're in breach of the [Be nice](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice) policy recently.

Comment: @Transistor Compensating with an answer.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie: Good work. Don't get too much like Catbert.

Comment: @Transistor It just bugs me a lot that many people think they can just design / change something without spending all the effort of learning circuits etc. I mean, it took me **years** to understand these things.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie: Sure, but let them down gently. If they're hanging from a bunch of helium balloons just shoot one of them so they don't get hurt when they hit the ground. I agree that with the democratisation of knowledge with the web that there are a lot of people doing things without much understanding. This is the state of the world!

Comment: I do want to note I'm no idiot, and forums do help shortcut work for things I don't do everyday. I've spent 20 years doing industrial automation and machine programming... common and proprietary languages. Motion Control is my expertise. I've worked on very complex machines requiring a lot of engineering expertise.  My analog circuits classes I took 20 years ago just aren't coming back to me like I hoped they would.

Comment: And I'll add I'm a member of all kinds of forums from drives, automation, Honda's, Ford's, John Deere tractors, etc. etc. and I always attempt to be courteous and respectful when some asks basic questions.  Some could be middle school kids just trying to do a science project, would be huge turnoff for them to be treated with disrespect in a field they are considering... my teenage son has a youtube channel I monitor and I noticed he replied once with a rude comment, I made him delete it and told him we wouldn't speak to people we didn't know that way.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a better solution:

I have drawn only 3 sections but you can make more if you like.

You do have to change the value of the 3 k ohm resistors to

*number of sections* x 1 k ohm

The 1 kohm is R10 on the bottom right.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fr0I6N.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When the water reaches all contacts the output voltage will be about Vcc/2
If you want to have a different value change R10.

Note that the water must also be in constant contact with the ground of this circuit. And that's also how you can test that it works, just connect  the contacts to ground to simulate that they're in the water.

Circuit description: poor man's resistor-DAC, it sums the current from each section into R10.

Comment: I really do appreciate the answer.  To make sure I understand the theory behind your answer.  The 3k Ohm resistors will allow more current to flow (resistors will be in parallel with each other which will lower the resistance of the circuit causing more current to flow through R10).   




So say I want 18 sections, I change the 3k Ohm resistors to 18k (or something off the shelf that is close) and then adjust R10 to get my max range... say I wanted 4VDC max I could change R10 to 4k Ohms if I did my math right.

Comment: When all the sections are on you get the highest output voltage. That voltage is determined by the voltage divider made by all the (in this case) 3 k resistors in parallel (so 1 k in total) and R10 so you'd get 5 V * R10 / (Rtot + R10) = 5 V * 1k /(1k+1k) = 5 V * 1/2 = 2.5 V Look up "voltage divider" for more info. Indeed you do not have to use 1k, 3K etc, it doesn't actually matter much since only the **ratio** is important. So if you have lots of 100k resistors, you can use those as well.

Comment: Ok. sounds like I have it down.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do this.

For clarity in the following schematics I replaced the PNPs with switches.

Your original schematic sort of works but it is not very linear.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fN81Ck.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]

Bimpelrekkie's proposal is much more linear but tails off at the high end.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5rqBv.png)</sup>

[image]

If you extend Bimpelrekkie's suggestion, and have dual rails available, you can sum the currents though op-amps and obtain a nice linear answer.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjrIDL.png)</sup>

[image]

Another method is to use resistor values calculated to produce linear values when combined in parallel as shown below.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxbleo.png)</sup>
[image]

**HOWEVER All of these solutions rely on the base currents being consistent on all the transistors and high enough to saturate the PNP transistors.**

Comment: Thanks for the additional suggestions, Trevor.  I think I will incorporate some of your options for sure.  I like the calculated resistor values for ease of build, as I haven't worked with op amps in some time.  But op amps sounds fun to try.

Comment: in your op amp example.  would i change R31 if I wanted to increase the voltage scale?  say to 4k ohm?  Or is it R32 I would want to change?

Comment: @driveguy R17 really sets the scale, the second opamp's primary function is an invertor, but you could turn it into an amplification stage or active filter or whatever.